# Graphene Python Lists resolve null for all fields

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python

I am working with GraphQL in python am trying to resolve list data but the fields are resolving null. How can i make them return the actual list data?

Here is a snippet of my code

```
import graphene


class User(graphene.ObjectType):
    """ Type definition for User """
    id = graphene.Int()
    username = graphene.String()
    email = graphene.String()

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    users = graphene.List(User)

    def resolve_users(self, args):
        resp = [{'id': 39330, 'username': 'RCraig', 'email': 
                 'WRussell@dolor.gov', 'teamId': 0}, {'id': 39331, 
                 'username': 'AHohmann','email': 'AMarina@sapien.com', 
                 'teamId': 0}]
        return  resp

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

The snippet is can tested at [graphene playground](http://graphene-python.org/playground/)

Here is my current query
[image: query]

and the undesired response
[image: graphQL response]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to return User's objects, not just dictionary:

```
import graphene


class User(graphene.ObjectType):
    """ Type definition for User """
    id = graphene.Int()
    username = graphene.String()
    email = graphene.String()

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    users = graphene.List(User)

    def resolve_users(self, args):
        resp = [User(id=39330, username='RCraig', email='WRussell@dolor.gov')]
        return  resp

schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
```

You can check in [playground](http://graphene-python.org/playground/?query=query%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20users%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20id%20%0A%20%20%20%20username%20%0A%20%20%20%20email%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A&schema=import%20graphene%0A%0A%0Aclass%20User%28graphene.ObjectType%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%22%22%22%20Type%20definition%20for%20User%20%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20id%20%3D%20graphene.Int%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20username%20%3D%20graphene.String%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20email%20%3D%20graphene.String%28%29%0A%0Aclass%20Query%28graphene.ObjectType%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20users%20%3D%20graphene.List%28User%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20resolve_users%28self%2C%20args%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20resp%20%3D%20%5BUser%28id%3D39330%2C%20username%3D%27RCraig%27%2C%20email%3D%27WRussell%40dolor.gov%27%29%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%20resp%0A%0Aschema%20%3D%20graphene.Schema%28query%3DQuery%29%0A).

Comment: This code returns only one list (one set of id,username,email). How do you return multiple sets?

Comment: @jigarshah I know this is late, but you just add more `User` objects to `resp` in the code above.